# Database Statistics or bechmark tools

Tags: database, postgresql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have to monitor database statistic for postgresql.In future it may change.So the tool which support multiple database server would be better.
The statistics  are like : 
1.  Query execution time.
2.  Number of queries that are executed per sec.
3.  Number of queries are still in execution.
4.  Ram usage of the query utlitization.

If any module available to integrate in my applications??

Comment: I suggest measuring response time as perceived by the users and the fraction of the response time that is spent in query processing. This way you will measure relevant the items right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A number of useful tools and methods are documented in the wiki:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logging_Difficult_Queries